# Convert a Flow to MutableStateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How do I convert a Flow to a MutableStateFlow?

There's a `stateIn` function that returns a StateFlow, but not a MutableStateFlow.

I need to be able to mutate the data for a use case like so:

```
private val someState = combine(flow1, flow2) { state1, state2 ->
        applySomeTransformation(state1, state2)
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, initialState)
    
    fun edit() {
        someState.update { //update }
    }
```

However, since `stateIn` returns a StateFlow, I cannot call update...

For now, I'm using this ugly workaround:

```
private val someState = MutableStateFlow(initialState)

    init {
        combine(flow1, flow2) { state1, state2 ->
            applySomeTransformation(state1, state2)
        }.onEach {
            someState.value = it
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

Since `someState` is now a MutableStateFlow, I can call update, but looks quite ugly.

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: What is your expected behavior? `stateIn()` means the value of the state flow is controlled by another flow. `MutableStateFlow` means the value is controller by us. They are rather contradicting cases.

Comment: Why would you want this?  Presumably you either want it to reflect the state from your other flows, or you want it to reflect the state from updates.  If you have this update state, then it's just going to get overwritten as soon as there are updates from the other flows.